# If a transformation of a random variable preserves its mean and variance, can it change the covariance with another random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two real-valued random variables in $L^2$, and let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a deterministic function such that $\mathbb E[f(X)] = \mathbb E[X]$ and $\mathrm{Var}(f(X)) = \mathrm{Var}(X)$.

Does
$$\mathrm{Cov}(f(X),Y) = \mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$$
hold necessarily?

Comment: I would guess the answer is no

Comment: No to the title, or no to the equality of covariances? Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $$X=Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1), \quad f(x)=-x.$$ It has the requested properties (since also $-X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$), but
$$ \text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \neq -E[X^2] + E[X]^2 = \text{Cov}(-X,Y).$$

Comment: Cheers! Thanks.